# Add records to existing Firebase Datamodel with Angularjs

Tags: set, firebase, angularfire

I have been scrambling my brains for hours trying to implement this code in the [Firebase Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) with my own solution.

I have a Posts.json as a data source in Firebase with the following structure example:

```
{
Title: "Cheese Fondling",

Body: "I love cheese, especially paneer mozzarella. Roquefort cheeseburger cut the cheese fondue edam taleggio cheese slices gouda. Dolcelatte croque monsieur cottage cheese camembert de normandie cheese slices st. agur blue cheese bavarian bergkase swiss. Edam cheesecake parmesan.",
}
```

I am not sure if I need to update its records via set() as the file already exists but as it does not work I attempted with Push, which still does not work.

My HTML form view looks as follows:

```
      <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="AddPost()">
            <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>{{addp.title}}</legend>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtTitle">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md"  ng-model="post.Title">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Textarea -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtPost">Post</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtPost" name="txtPost"  ng-model="post.Body"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="singlebutton" ng-disabled="!post.Title || !post.Body" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Publish" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The controller is added separately via state:

```
  .state('AddPost', {
      url: '/blog',
      controller: 'AddPostCtrl as addp',
      templateUrl: 'blog.html',
      title: 'Blog'
    })
```

This is the controller code:

```
    controllersModule.controller('AddPostCtrl', ["$scope", '$firebaseArray',
      function($scope, $firebaseArray){
         $scope.AddPost = function() {

   var title = $scope.post.Title;
   var post = $scope.post.Body;
   $scope.refPosts = postsArray;

   var ref = new Firebase('https://<DATASOURCE>.firebaseio.com/');
   var refPosts = ref.child("Posts")
   var postsArray = $firebaseArray(refPosts);

   postsArray.$add({ Title: Title, Body: Body }).then(function(ref) {
        console.log(ref);
        console.log("It worked");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
        console.log("It did not work");
    });
}
    }]);
```

EDITED ABOVE. AND ALSO ADDED THIS IN THE POSTS VIEW:

```
<div class="meeting" ng-repeat="post in refPosts">
    <h5>{{post.Title}}</h5>
    <p>{{post.Body}}</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While AngularFire and Firebase's JavaScript SDK interact with each other fine, you cannot call methods from one on objects from the other. You either have a Firebase JavaScript reference, on which you call `ref.push()` or you have an AngularFire `$firebaseArray`, on which you call `array.$add()`.

**With Firebase.push()**

```
$scope.AddPost = function() {

   var title = $scope.post.Title;
   var post = $scope.post.Body;

   var ref = new Firebase("https://<DATA SOURCE>.firebaseio.com/");
   var refPosts = ref.child("Posts")

   refPosts.push({ Title: title, Body: body }, function(error) {
       if (error) {
           console.log("Error:", error);
       }
       else {
           console.log("It worked");
       }
   });
}
```

**With $firebaseArray.$add()**

```
 $scope.AddPost = function() {

   var title = $scope.post.Title;
   var post = $scope.post.Body;

   var ref = new Firebase("https://<DATA SOURCE>.firebaseio.com/");
   var refPosts = ref.child("Posts")
   var postsArray = $firebase(refPosts);

   postsArray.$add({ Title: title, Body: body }).then(function(ref) {
        console.log(ref);
        console.log("It worked");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
        console.log("It did not work");
    });
}
```

Comment: I have used your Firebase Array option (see edited code above), however it still does not work. I added an ngrepeat to the page to see if it is connecting but nothing even loads and the following error comes up in the console: ReferenceError: Title is not defined.

Comment: You've mistyped your variable names. You declare the variable as: `var title = $scope.post.Title;`, yet you then use it as `postsArray.$add({ Title: Title,`. Mixing and matching variable names like that will never work. This will:  `postsArray.$add({ Title: title,...`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! These spellings always get me. I have managed to fix it and everything now works. A combination of your answers and my brain meltdown :-)

Answer (score 0):

So here is the final code. It does help to have other people's feedback:

```
controllersModule.controller('AddPostCtrl', ["$scope", '$firebaseArray',
  function($scope, $firebaseArray){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://<DATASOURCE>.firebaseio.com/Posts');
    var myPosts = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.myPosts = myPosts;

    $scope.AddPost = function() {
        myPosts.$add({
            Title: $scope.post.Title,
            Body: $scope.post.Body
        }).then(function(ref) {
        console.log(ref);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
    }
}]);
```